# How to use setOnAction with checkBox?

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a pizza ordering GUI in javaFX using the factory design pattern, I understand the fact that in the factory pattern that all decision making goes in the factory class. Now I have some Check Box created that the user has to select from to make their order. How do I use the `checkbox.isSelected()` in the factory class to do it or is there something else I'm missing or need to do?

This is the GUI

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PizzaGUI extends Application {

    static  ArrayList<String> pza_tpg = new ArrayList<String>();
    static  ArrayList<String> pza_tpe = new ArrayList<String>();
    static  ArrayList<String> pza_sze = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage Stage) {
        
        //pizza toppings    
        pza_tpg.add("Tomatos");
        pza_tpg.add("Green Peppers");
        pza_tpg.add("Black Olives");
        pza_tpg.add("Mushrooms");
        pza_tpg.add("Extra Cheese");
        pza_tpg.add("Pepperoni");
        pza_tpg.add("Sausage");
        
        //pizza size
        pza_sze.add("Small");
        pza_sze.add("Medium");
        pza_sze.add("Large");
        pza_sze.add("Family");
        
        
        //pizza type
        pza_tpe.add("Thin Crust");
        pza_tpe.add("Medium Crust");
        pza_tpe.add("Crust Lover");
        
        
        
        
        Group root = new Group();
        
        
        Label wce= new Label("Welcome to OOPII_PizzaMania");
        wce.setFont(new Font(30));
        wce.setLayoutX(110);
        wce.setLayoutY(80);
        root.getChildren().add(wce);
        
        
        Label tops= new Label("Each Topping: $1.50");
        tops.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
        tops.setLayoutX(60);
        tops.setLayoutY(140);
        root.getChildren().add(tops);
        
        
        CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox("Tomato");  
        CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox("Green Pepper"); 
        CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox("Black Olives"); 
        CheckBox cb4 = new CheckBox("Mushrooms"); 
        CheckBox cb5 = new CheckBox("Extra Cheese"); 
        CheckBox cb6 = new CheckBox("Pepperoni"); 
        CheckBox cb7 = new CheckBox("Sausage"); 
        cb1.setLayoutX(70);
        cb1.setLayoutY(165);
        cb2.setLayoutX(70);
        cb2.setLayoutY(185);
        cb3.setLayoutX(70);
        cb3.setLayoutY(205);
        cb4.setLayoutX(70);
        cb4.setLayoutY(225);
        cb5.setLayoutX(70);
        cb5.setLayoutY(245);
        cb6.setLayoutX(70);
        cb6.setLayoutY(265);
        cb7.setLayoutX(70);
        cb7.setLayoutY(286);
        root.getChildren().addAll(cb1,cb2,cb3,cb4,cb5,cb6,cb7);

        
        Label PSize= new Label("Pizza Size");
        PSize.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
        PSize.setLayoutX(250);
        PSize.setLayoutY(140);
        root.getChildren().add(PSize);
        
        ToggleGroup group2 = new ToggleGroup();  
        RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("Small: $25.00");  
        RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("Medium: $50.00"); 
        RadioButton rb3 = new RadioButton("Large: $75.00"); 
       RadioButton rb4 = new RadioButton("Family: $130.00"); 
      rb1.setToggleGroup(group2);  
       rb2.setToggleGroup(group2);
       rb3.setToggleGroup(group2);  
       rb4.setToggleGroup(group2);  
       
       rb1.setLayoutX(240);
       rb1.setLayoutY(165);
       rb2.setLayoutX(240);
       rb2.setLayoutY(185);
       rb3.setLayoutX(240);
       rb3.setLayoutY(205);
       rb4.setLayoutX(240);
       rb4.setLayoutY(225);
       root.getChildren().addAll(rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4);
       
       Label type= new Label("Pizza Type");
        type.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
        type.setLayoutX(400);
        type.setLayoutY(140);
        root.getChildren().add(type);
        
        ToggleGroup group3 = new ToggleGroup();  
        RadioButton rb5 = new RadioButton("Thin Crust");  
        RadioButton rb6 = new RadioButton("Medium Crust"); 
        RadioButton rb7 = new RadioButton("Crust Lover"); 
      
      rb5.setToggleGroup(group3);  
       rb6.setToggleGroup(group3);
       rb7.setToggleGroup(group3);  
      
       
       rb5.setLayoutX(405);
       rb5.setLayoutY(165);
       rb6.setLayoutX(405);
       rb6.setLayoutY(185);
       rb7.setLayoutX(405);
       rb7.setLayoutY(205);
       
       root.getChildren().addAll(rb5,rb6,rb7);
       
        CheckBox mc = new CheckBox("Members Card");  
        mc.setLayoutX(240);
        mc.setLayoutY(255);
        root.getChildren().add(mc);
        
        Button bt1= new Button("Place Order");
        bt1.setLayoutX(245);
        bt1.setLayoutY(300);
        root.getChildren().add(bt1);
        
        Button bt2= new Button("Print all Orders");
        bt2.setLayoutX(445);
        bt2.setLayoutY(600);
        root.getChildren().add(bt2);
        
        
        Label dets= new Label("Your Order Details");
        dets.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
        dets.setLayoutX(45);
        dets.setLayoutY(350);
        root.getChildren().add(dets);
        
        TextArea ta= new TextArea();
        double height= 140;
        ta.setPrefHeight(height);
        ta.setLayoutX(45);
        ta.setLayoutY(380);
        root.getChildren().add(ta);
        
        
        Scene s = new Scene(root, 570, 650);
        Stage.setTitle("Sample Application");
        Stage.setScene(s);
        Stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the factory Class

```
public class PizzaFactory {

    public Pizza makePizza(String newPizza) {
        

        
        if(newPizza== null) {
            return null;
        }
        
        if(cb1.isSelected()) {
            
        }
        return null;
    
    }
}
```

Edit: cb1 is an error in if(cb1.isSelected())

Comment: Your factory shouldn't access the UI elements. The parameter passed to the `makePizza` method is supposed to specify how the pizza should be made (perhaps a `String` is not appropriate here).

Comment: @James_D so how can I make it in factory class and I was following a tutorial video that why I used ```String```.

Comment: Nothing in that comment seems to make sense.

Comment: @James_D what would be appropriate to use instead of ```String```

Comment: You could create a class encapsulating the information you need to create a pizza. Or use multiple parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pizza builder method shouldn't be accessing the layout elements, like the CheckBoxes.  You should follow some kind of an MVC structure, separate the layout from the data and pass the data (the model) from your controller to your pizza builder.

Something like this:

```
public class Pizza extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        PizzaModel model = new PizzaModel();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(buildPizzaView(model, () -> System.out.println(buildPizza(model)))));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static String buildPizza(PizzaModel model) {
        return "Here's your pizza! " + (model.isHasMushrooms() ? "Mushrooms " : "") + (model.isHasPepperoni() ? "Pepperoni" : "");
    }

    private static Region buildPizzaView(PizzaModel model, Runnable actionHandler) {
        Button button = new Button("Make Pizza");
        button.setOnAction(evt -> actionHandler.run());
        VBox results = new VBox(10,
                                createBoundCheckBox("Pepperoni", model.hasPepperoniProperty()),
                                createBoundCheckBox("Mushrooms", model.hasMushroomsProperty()),
                                button);
        return results;

    }

    private static Node createBoundCheckBox(String label, BooleanProperty boundProperty) {
        CheckBox results = new CheckBox(label);
        results.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(boundProperty);
        return results;
    }

    class PizzaModel {
        BooleanProperty hasPepperoni = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        BooleanProperty hasMushrooms = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        public boolean isHasPepperoni() {
            return hasPepperoni.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty hasPepperoniProperty() {
            return hasPepperoni;
        }

        public boolean isHasMushrooms() {
            return hasMushrooms.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty hasMushroomsProperty() {
            return hasMushrooms;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your use of `Group` and then setting layout [X,Y] is making a lot of work for yourself.  Use one or more of the layout regions like GridPane, BorderPane, VBox, HBox or FlowPane and you'll save yourself a lot of effort.